# How does C++ compute the absolute value of a complex number, preventing overflow?

Tags: c++, numeric, floating-accuracy, complex-numbers

The C++ header `<complex>` provides `abs(z)` and `norm(z)`.

The norm of a complex number z=x+iy is `norm(z)`:=x^2+y^2.

The absolute value of z is `abs(z)`:=sqrt(norm(z)).

However, the following example shows that `abs(z)` must be implemented differently, since it does not overflow although `norm(z)` does. At least, it does not overflow under g++ 6.2.1.

Is this non-overflow guaranteed by the standard? How is it achieved?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
typedef std::complex<double> complex_t;

int main()
{
    complex_t z = { 3e200, 4e200 };
    double a = abs(z);
    double n = norm(z);

    std::cout << a << " -> " << std::isinf(a) << "\n";
    std::cout << n << " -> " << std::isinf(n) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5e+200 -> 0
inf -> 1
```

Comment: Look at the implementation in the header file. At least on my system, the max of abs(real part), abs(imag part) is used to first divide, then multiply. This may be the reason overflow is avoided.

Comment: It looks like libstdc++ does it the other way around: the calculation for `abs` is direct ([source](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/complex.html#572)), the calculation for the norm squares the absolute value ([source](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/complex.html#652)). Abs also divided both real and imaginary parts by their maximum, probably to prevent overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::complex::abs` is equivalent to `std::hypot` function, which is indeed guaranteed to avoid overflow and underflow at intermediate stages of the computation.

[Wikipedia page on Hypot function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot) gives some insight on the implementation.

I'll quote the pseudocode just in case:

```
  // hypot for (x, y) != (0, 0)
double hypot(double x,double y)
{
    double t;
    x = abs(x);
    y = abs(y);
    t = min(x,y);
    x = max(x,y);
    t = t/x;
    return x*sqrt(1+t*t);
}
```

Comment: Jut to note that, this is not exactly what libm will do. This implementation will not give a 1ULP error bound

Comment: @YanZhou oh yeah, precision-wise this pseudocode is not what happens at all; however it explains the overflow situation. "Real code" would be something like [this](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_hypot.c)